# Can Django be configured without httpd.conf modifications?

Tags: django, apache, centos, virtualenv, wsgi

So I had someone working with me who setup the server functionality of the Django site. It is working great directly on the IP in the browser. So we just finished building the site, and want to hook up the domain.

I checked `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` and that file has nothing related to the Django site. I've setup a few Django sites in the past, but I have always used `httpd.conf`.

Where could he have possibly set up the WSGI?

Version details:

CentOS release 6.6 (Final)

Apache server version: Apache/2.2.15

Python 2.7.9 (via Virtual Env) with Django 1.6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux systems, additions for specific sites are generally never stuck in the httpd.conf file. Instead they would be in separate files for each site under a sites-available directory, which in turn would be symlinked into a sites-enabled directory. The main Apache configuration files would then use the Include directive to include all files from the sites-enabled directory.

Comment: Okay, so you're thinking there is an `include` line in the configuration file that will lead me to what I'm looking for? I'll check, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure Apache is actually how it's configured, you can find the path of the running instance with:

```
$ ps -ef | grep apache
apache 28400    966  0 April28 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2
```

You can then take the path (from the end of the above), and append the `-V` argument to find the configuration file:

```
$ /usr/sbin/apache2 -V | grep SERVER_CONFIG_FILE
-D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="/etc/apache2/apache2.conf"
```